# Where does at&t assembly syntax come from?

Tags: assembly

Intel makes microprocessor, so he could define the instruction format and its corresponse assembly of its processors,so why AT&T could also create its syntax of assembly language?

thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This google book link ([Assembly Language Step-by-Step: Programming with Linux By Jeff Duntemann p. 444](http://books.google.com/books?id=8iR-pBg2aAwC&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=at%26T+assembly+notation&source=bl&ots=qRuZmMJZZ_&sig=kpVVDALWE17TNQZWMTGTwL6j4C4&hl=en&ei=jIXvStHkOIi0sgOu7eiABg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=at%26T%20assembly%20notation&f=false)) matches what I would have guessed: that AT&T developed the syntax for use on a number of different platforms.

AT&T played a major role in the history of computers.  AT&T (Bell Labs) was the source of Unix, the C programming language, and many other fundamental tools that we continue to use today.

Comment: So... for the same reason that musical notation uses a lot of Italian words!

Comment: According to the book, at&t try to define this 'portable-notation' assembly syntax,then what are the platforms that support at&t syntax anyway?As the book says, its really strange that the assembly itself is to be portable on multi-platforms,since their instruction sets varies from one to another.

Comment: Some of the syntax stays the same across platforms: use of % on register names, $ on immediate values, and "opcode source, destination" format.  This syntax is available, via as or gas, on many platforms including x86, MIPS, PowerPC, PDP-11, probably a few thousand chips.  HOWEVER, because the operations supported, registers provided, memory layouts, and details vary between platforms, programs written to the AT&T syntax do not "recompile" on any other platform.  The common syntax was used because the assembler served as a 'back end' for the C compiler, i.e., it received generated input.

Comment: @Artelius: <irony>Bravi!  Bravi!  Bravissimi!</irony>